# OnClick event for dynamic button?

Tags: delphi, events

Before I start I must state that no other stack overflow post on this topic had helped me yet

I have a dynamic button called by btnApply

It is created dynamically on a dynamic form frmSort by a on click event of static button btnSort on static form frmTable

Under the global scope var of frmTable is declared

```
btnApply: TButton;
Procedure btnApplyClick(Sender:TObject);
//other vars
```

Under the btnSort on click

```
//other code
btnApply:= TButton.create(frmSort);
//all its properties
BtnApply.onclick:= btnApplyClick;
//other code
```

Then later

```
Procedure btnApplyClick(Sender:TObject);
Begin
  //it's code it has to execute
End;
```

I get an error message at the "BtnApply.onclick:= btnApplyClick;"
Line of incompatible types between method pointer and regular procedure

How do I make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `btnApplyClick` needs to be a method of an object. Since the button has to be on a form to be useful anyway, make it a method of the form itself:

```
type
  TfrmSort = class(TForm)
    // UI controls listed here
  public
    procedure btnApplyClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TfrmSort.btnApplyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TButton).Caption := 'You clicked me';
end;

procedure TfrmSort.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Btn: TButton;
begin
  Btn := TButton.Create(Self);
  Btn.Parent := Self;
  Btn.Top := 100;
  Btn.Left := 100;
  Btn.OnClick := btnApplyClick;
end;
```

If for some reason you can't make it a form method (although I can't see how this would be the case for a visual control), you can make it a method of any object, like this:

```
implementation

// You must use StdCtrls in order to have the types available if
// it's not already in your uses clause
type
  TDummyButtonClickObj = class
    class procedure ButtonClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
  end;

{ TDummyButtonClickObj }

class procedure TDummyButtonClickObj.ButtonClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TButton).Caption := 'You clicked me.';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TButton.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Top := 100;
    Left := 100;
    Caption := 'Click here';
    OnClick := TDummyButtonClickObj.ButtonClickHandler;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I see your first point but unfortunately my frmSort is not declared as a type like the frmTable, but rather as frmSort:TForm along with the btnApply:TButton in the var . And I am an inexperienced programmer so I don't know classes either. Can I bypass the type frmSort = class(TForm) thing or is it the only way

Comment: It is also possible to use a **non-member** procedure as the event handler. It just takes a couple of extra steps to set up. Add an extra explicit parameter to account for the `Self` pointer: `procedure btnApplyClick(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);` and then use the `TMethod` record to assign the procedure to the button: `var M: TMethod; M.Code := @btnApplyClick; M.Data := nil; BtnApply.onclick := TNotifyEvent(M);`

Answer (score 9):

As others have stated, the event handler **should** be a member of a class.  That is what the event is expecting.  However, it is also possible to use a **non-member** procedure as the event handler. It just takes a couple of extra steps to set up.

1. Add an extra explicit parameter to account for the `Self` pointer:

   ```
   procedure btnApplyClick(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
   ```
2. Use the `TMethod` record to assign the procedure to the button:

   ```
   var
     btnApply: TButton;
     M: TMethod;
     //other vars

   Procedure btnApplyClick(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);

   ...

   btnApply := TButton.create(frmSort);
   //all its properties
   M.Code := @btnApplyClick;
   M.Data := nil; // can be anything you want passed to the Self parameter
   BtnApply.onclick := TNotifyEvent(M);
   //other code

   ...

   procedure btnApplyClick(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
   Begin
     // code to execute
   End;
   ```

Comment: Ken's answer worked, but I will try this too. Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend this at all. Far better is to use a class method to avoid such trickery if you need to do this without having an instance.

Comment: Such is your opinion. There are useful cases where this comes in handy, like passing custom context information directly into the event handler without having to store it elsewhere, like in the control's `Tag` property. Use it or not, it is your choice.  I use this approach all the time when using console apps to test event-driven code without creating UIs for them.